# shell change date within a string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, cygwin

I found some sed examples for my dilemma. current text file is like below.

```
 076411-160DL        0000000052220420    000005212635883-0003-0
 138574A             0000000120220421    000012012630637-0003-1
 146054A             0000000420220422    000042012634007-0003-1
 138575A             0000000240220421    000024012630638-0003-1
 145683C             0000000145220422    000014512634671-0003-1
 137611B             0000000130220419    000013012632286-0003-0
 137618C             0000000120220420    000012012635623-0003-0
```

I am only changing date in the second column but I need to leave it as is and just change to the current date then out to a new file. I have the first part seperated using `grep -v "\0003-0" *.txt` Then I seperate the 0003-0 with `grep -h "\0003-0"` I then use a sed to change format and this is where it is almost there but due to numbers in front of the date it is not consistent.

```
sed -r "s/[2]{2}[0-8]{2}[0-9]{2}/$(date '+%y%m%d')/g"
```

I get it mostly how I want it but if there is a group with 8 zeros and only 1 other digit before the date I get something on the end of the new date such as 9 or 0. Any tips would be awesome. Thanks

I am only changing the date where the file ends in 0003-0
There is a space before the first column I was not aware of until now.

expected output would be

```
 076411-160DL        0000000052220425    000005212635883-0003-0
 138574A             0000000120220421    000012012630637-0003-1
 146054A             0000000420220422    000042012634007-0003-1
 138575A             0000000240220421    000024012630638-0003-1
 145683C             0000000145220422    000014512634671-0003-1
 137611B             0000000130220425    000013012632286-0003-0
 137618C             0000000120220425    000012012635623-0003-0
```

Comment: why `grep -v "\0003-0"` instead of `grep -v "0003-0"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date=$(date +%y%m%d)
sed -E '/0003-0$/{s/ ([^ ]{1,10})[^ ]* / \1'"$date"' /2}'
```

Note that your data has a single space before the first column.

Explanation:

TLDR: Make a pattern to match fields, which also captures (up to) the first ten characters of the field for a back-reference, and substitute the second field.

- First, filter for lines ending in `0003-0`.
- Then target the second field of each line, by using a pattern of "space, then at least one non-space character, then space".
- The `2` at the very end means substitute the second (or N) instance of the match pattern. Hence our pattern targets the second field only.
- The pattern captures (up to) the first ten characters of this field (using parentheses), so we can back-reference them in the replacement (using `\1`) and discards the remaining (six) date characters, which we replace with `$date`.
- `{1,10}` needs to be a range of at least one character, because it must match both the first and second field, to enable us to specify the second field with `2`.

Edit:

Gives:

```
 076411-160DL        0000000052220426    000005212635883-0003-0
 138574A             0000000120220421    000012012630637-0003-1
 146054A             0000000420220422    000042012634007-0003-1
 138575A             0000000240220421    000024012630638-0003-1
 145683C             0000000145220422    000014512634671-0003-1
 137611B             0000000130220426    000013012632286-0003-0
 137618C             0000000120220426    000012012635623-0003-0
```

Comment: Thanks for the break down I really do appreciate it. I still haven't gotten it to work however. My text file is larger I just didn't want to post it all. It follows the same patters throughout so it should not matter except there is a # on the last line by itself.

Comment: Is there a space before the first field in your text file?

Comment: Forgot to mention that you are correct about the space at the beginning of the first column. I am assuming it will always be there.

Comment: I just corrected the quoting, although it shouldn't change much (except the `$` in `0003-0$` is now preserved properly). It certainly works for me on your example. I'll post my output. You can try both copy pasting the command and re-typing it - characters can get mixed up either with either method.

Comment: Thanks to all for the help. After running dos2unix and using this script. It was successful.
`date=$(date +%y%m%d)
sed -E '/0003-0$/{s/ ([^ ]{1,10})[^ ]* / \1'"$date"' /2}'`

Answer (score 1):

Adding a pattern match to OP's current `sed` code:

```
$ sed -r "/-0003-0$/s/[2]{2}[0-8]{2}[0-9]{2}/$(date '+%y%m%d')/g" file
 076411-160DL        0000000052204250    000005212635883-0003-0
 138574A             0000000120220421    000012012630637-0003-1
 146054A             0000000420220422    000042012634007-0003-1
 138575A             0000000240220421    000024012630638-0003-1
 145683C             0000000145220422    000014512634671-0003-1
 137611B             0000000130220425    000013012632286-0003-0
 137618C             0000000120220425    000012012635623-0003-0
```

But this fails to update the first line.

One possible tweak to address the 'middle' field:

```
$ sed -r "/-0003-0$/s/( [0-9]{10})([0-9]{6}) /\1$(date '+%y%m%d') /" file
 076411-160DL        0000000052220425    000005212635883-0003-0
 138574A             0000000120220421    000012012630637-0003-1
 146054A             0000000420220422    000042012634007-0003-1
 138575A             0000000240220421    000024012630638-0003-1
 145683C             0000000145220422    000014512634671-0003-1
 137611B             0000000130220425    000013012632286-0003-0
 137618C             0000000120220425    000012012635623-0003-0
```

Comment: Out of all of these answers are they all doing everything with a 1 line code or are you using the parts where I have grepped sections of the file? I tried all in 1 line and I have had no success. All great suggestions I guess I just need a bit more context.

Comment: @fletching all of the (current) answers are using a single `sed` script to replace your combination of `grep` and `sed`; I just checked and all 4 (current) answers *do* generate what you've listed as your expected output; what could be impacting your ability to get the answers to work for you is if your actual data file has Windows/DOS line endings in which case none of the current tests for `0003-0$` will succeed; run `head -3 your_data_file | od -c` and if the output contains `\r \n` as line endings then you do in fact have Windows/DOS line endings (ie, the `\r` is causing problems)

Comment: if you have Windows/DOS line endings you have a couple options ... 1) modify our answers and change `0003-0$` to `0003-0\r$` ... or 2) remove the `\r` characters from the source file (eg, `dos2unix your_data_file`) and then run any of these `sed` answers (as is)

Comment: very helpful as I ran this test and I do indeed have \r in several areas. I will add a dos2unix command at the beginning of the script and see if that helps if not I will add the \r and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting single `sed` command:

```
 sed -r '/0003-0$/s|([[:digit:]]{6}) |'$(date +%y%m%d)' |'
```